# numpy mean/std dev of arrays of various lengths

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays of size 5. All of the arrays inside the list are of different lengths. I need a single array that holds the means of the elements and a single array that holds the standard deviations.
Example:

```
[10, 10, 10, 10]
[ 8,  8,  8,  8, 8]
[12, 12, 12]
```

I want:

```
[10, 10, 10, 9, 8] and
[1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 0]
```

(I made up the std devs)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to fill the *empty places* with `NaNs`, resulting in a 2D array and then use `nan` specific NumPy arithmetic tools, such as `nanmean` (compute mean skipping the `NaNs`) etc. along the appropriate axis, like so -

```
In [5]: import itertools

# a is input list of lists/arrays
In [48]: ar = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*a, fillvalue=np.nan)))

In [49]: np.nanmean(ar,axis=1)
Out[49]: array([10., 10., 10.,  9.,  8.])

In [50]: np.nanstd(ar,axis=1)
Out[50]: array([1.63299316, 1.63299316, 1.63299316, 1.        , 0.        ])
```

Another way is to convert to a pandas dataframe such that *empty places* are filled with `NaNs` and then use dataframe methods that account for the `NaNs` natively, like so -

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [18]: df.mean(0).values
Out[18]: array([10., 10., 10.,  9.,  8.])

In [19]: df.std(0,ddof=0).values
Out[19]: array([1.63299316, 1.63299316, 1.63299316, 1.        , 0.        ])
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I didn't even think about NaN's not being included in mean/std dev.